# Convergence of a sequence of matrices

Tags: matrices, convergence-divergence

Let $A$ be a $n×m$ matrix with real entries, and let $B = AA^ t $and let $\alpha$ be the supremum
of $x ^t Bx$ where supremum is taken over all vectors $x ∈ \mathbb R ^n$ with norm less than or equal
to 1. Consider
$C_ k = I +\sum_{j=1}^k
B ^j $.

Show that the sequence of matrices $C_ k$ converges if and only if $\alpha  < 1.$

Any help on how to solve this.Please dont give the solution ;just give the outline.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: $B$ being positive definite, $\alpha$ is the operator norm of $B$.

Comment: I can see that $B$ is symmetric and hence orthogonally diagonalisable but cant get your hints .Can  I take it from here?

Comment: I'm really not sure whether this hint should be a lone-standing answer. I think it would be better placed as a comment.

Comment: A complete answer was explicitly not wanted.

Comment: @learnmore As you say, $B$ is orthogonally diagonalisable.  What is the operator norm of a diagonal matrix with positive diagonal elements?

Answer (score 0):

As pointed out by Robert Israel, $\alpha$ is the operator norm of $B$, i.e. $||B||= \alpha$, one should show that $({\bf 1}-B)^{-1}$ exists, and then the sum should converge to

$$ \sum_{j=1}^{\infty} B^j =  ({\bf 1}-B)^{-1} - {\bf 1}$$

This happens precisely because $\alpha <1$, as in the usual geometrical series:

$$ \sum_{j=1}^{\infty}\alpha^j = (1-\alpha)^{-1} -1 $$

And because if $\alpha <1$ then all eigenvalues of $B$ have absolute value smaller than 1, hence ${\bf 1} - B$ is not singular.

$$ \lim_{k \to \infty} C_k = ({\bf 1} - B)^{-1}$$

Since $B$ is diagonalisable, you can work in the basis where $B$ is diagonal, then each diagonal entry is independent and you will get geometrical series in each entry which you can analise.